# Aligning a listing environment within a paragraph

Tags: listings, inline

I have the following code that displays a listing in a paragraph. However, because there are not so many line of code, I would like to move it to the right and the paragraph be on the left hand side. I'm wondering how I can do this.

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
  \vspace{-0.2cm}
  \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize,label= mylabel, caption = mycaption}
     LOC1 
     LOC2
     LOC3
     LOC4 
  \end{lstlisting}
  \vspace{-0.2cm}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: wrapfig is probably the package you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`wrapfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfloat}{lstlisting}{O}{5cm}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize,label= mylabel, caption =mycaption]
LOC1 
LOC2
LOC3
LOC4 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{wrapfloat}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]